# Account used to Deploy not same as account associated with contract

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment

So I am testing out a new contract I have been working on in Remix.

I expected that the Account I selected would be the one associated with the actual contract, but it is not.

In fact, I tried it a second time and got a different contract again:
[image]

Could this have something to do with the fact that I am not currently logged in to Metamask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ethereum, there are two kinds of accounts: contracts and external accounts. Every account is identified by an address, and all accounts share the same address space.

So, every time you deploy a new contract you will get a different address and this has nothing to do with from which account you are deploying the smart contract.

Refer the following blog for more details -

https://hackernoon.com/getting-deep-into-evm-how-ethereum-works-backstage-ac7efa1f0015

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you, also I see that it is within the console in Remix that I see the Account it was deployed from.